# как совершать следующее действие с помощью selenium Python после загрузки элемента на странице

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sleep

Друзья, добрый день! Хожу Селениумом по облачной 1-С ке. Возникла потребность совершать какое-то действие после загрузки определенного элемента страницы, а не всей страницы целиком. Пробовал два метода:
`wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located())` и ожидание до загрузки необходимых слов, например:
`wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"userName"))).click()`

или

`wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located())` со схожей логикой, описанной выше.

Но периодически код ломается. Значит, что-то происходит не так. Приходится втыкать костыли типа sleep, но они по-разному работают на разных машинах (в зависимости от того, как быстро грузятся страницы при разной скорости интернета).

Какие методы можно использовать, чтобы получать гарантированный результат, а не 20% успеха?

Answer (score 0):

Селениум не начинает работу пока страница не загрузится полностью, после того как страница загрузилась, он начинает искать те элементы которые Вы прописали.
Нужно смотреть ошибки, почему он отлетает? К примеру если по таймауту, значит селектор указан неправильно, и селениум отвалился по ожиданию - "wait".

Comment: Если б селектор был указан неверно, он отваливался бы каждый раз. Но каждый раз он не отваливается. Когда-то отрабатывает корректно. 
В селениуме же есть модуль ЕС. Если я верно понимаю, он как раз и существует в т.ч. для того чтобы не ждать всей загрузки страницы, а работает по принципу "стало видимым", "стало кликабельным" и пр.

Comment: Ну тут я бессилен, нужно смотреть код или ключевые функции, страницу. Но полагаю информация конфиденциальна.
Могу лишь посоветовать Вам пройтись по шагам вашей программы, то есть, все селекторы которые Вы выписали, повторите те же действия, что и Ваш код, с тем же селекторами, возможно ломается по селектору на каком-то конкретном шаге. Опять же, раз отваливается "через раз", значит надо найти причину почему через раз. Укажите побольше ожидание wait.
И всё же хотелось бы видеть ошибку, проблема может быть где угодно) и слипами Вы вряд ли решите ее. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Могу закинуть код и записать скрин происходящего. Что скажете?

Comment: Поддерживаю, ожидаю